# Value Object and View Model Property

Tags: wpf, mvvm, domain-driven-design, inotifypropertychanged

I am working on a solution that used DDD for architecture.  I have a property in my ViewModel which points to a ValueObject, the view model also implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface.  The value of the ValueObject will change as a user enters data on the front end.  The problem I am running into is the value object is suppose to be immutable.  How can I work around this issue?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you can edit something, then there must be a mutable container for the immutable value.** Therefore, your viewmodel should act on the mutable container rather than on the immutable value directly.

An integer is an example of such an immutable value object: the `Int32` type does not have any members that allow you to change the state of the object. You can only *replace* an integer, not change it. So a view model for an integer would look like this:

```
public MutableIntegerViewModel
{
    private readonly mutableInteger;

    public MutableIntegerViewModel(MutableInteger mutableInteger)
    {
        this.mutableInteger = mutableInteger;
    }

    public string DisplayText
    {
        get
        {
            return this.mutableInteger.Value.ToString(
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        }
        set
        {
           this.mutableInteger.Value = 
               Int32.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        }
    }
}
```

Where `MutableInteger` is just this:

```
public class MutableInteger
{
   public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

I've omitted error handling and change notification here, but hopefully you get the idea.

Also note this example is not really different from the typical example of a `Customer` class with a `FirstName` and a `LastName`. Strings are also immutable, so again we have a mutable container for immutable values.

Comment: I was thinking down the same path as the solution your specifying here but the unfortunate consequence is that it puts a burden on your DDD model to have a generic container for this value object otherwise a new ViewModel would have to be created for each container that wanted to allow editing of the same value object. Perhaps there is some way to keep the container itself in the ViewModel without making things overly complex...